# inspect data (url variable) before inserting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, filter

My php script is posting bad urls that ajax send to it.  When I try to filter the url and cancel the insert into mysql, it doesn't work.  What I want to do is verify the $link variable if it a link.  If not, don't post data to mysql. Can i know what I did wrong and how to fix it?   Thank you :)
Here is my code

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$link = $_POST['new'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

// PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($link);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$size = mysql_real_escape_string($size);
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);

if (filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {} else {
  echo "URL is NOT valid";
  mysql_close($con);
  exit();
}

$check = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE  link = '{$link}';");

if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) {
    // insert

    $sql="INSERT INTO links (link, name, size, category) VALUES ('$link','$name','$size','$cat')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added.  Redirecting!";


    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I was going to post the same comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
if(filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED) === false){
    echo "URL is NOT valid";
    mysql_close($con);
    exit();
}
```

Your are right `xxxhxtxtp://example.com` will pass as valid url.

Try it with `preg_match` instead.

```
if (!preg_match("#^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-_.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}#i", $link)) {
    echo "URL is NOT valid";
    mysql_close($con);
    exit();
}
```

With this regex you need to have http(s) scheme. So you can search for another regex if that don't work for you.

Comment: it still posting the invalid url to mysql.

Comment: please post an example how the url is looking

Comment: the url I want to post is ----> http://example.com/#![somerandomkeys]![somerandomkeys]  or like this one: https://mega.co.nz/#!nMYBFJIJ!QZQXh1NNxiDGyoFqUpHPGWnwGpR4E8Er1K3mRDrRDn8   I dont want to post url like this --->xxxhxtxtp://example.com or a url that is not complete.

Comment: The code that you gave me works to block bad urls without http(s).  But if the url contain http(s) and before the http(s), there are bad characters, the query will run anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much!  It works! For the past 4 hours, I was looking for a solution and you got it! ;D  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? Perhaps you need a regex solution.

```
if (filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE  link = '{$link}';");

    if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) {
        // insert

        $sql="INSERT INTO links (link, name, size, category) VALUES ('$link','$name','$size','$cat')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        echo "1 record added.  Redirecting!";


        mysql_close($con);
    }
} else {
  echo "URL is NOT valid";
  mysql_close($con);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: It still posting the bad url.  If i post this not working url                          ---> "sdsdhttp://example.com", it will insert it in mysql

Comment: @user1932820 Do you want to validate or do you want to clean them?

Comment: Thank you, redreggae gave me the solution!